# Why does the write speed keep changing, on a msdos file-system on toshiba 64Gb USB flashdrive

Tags: flash-memory, write, slowdown

I have just bought a new 64gb toshiba 2.0usb flashdrive and put 13gb on it that took about 1 1/2 hours to transfer (max).  But it started out saying about 7/8mb transfer and went to 1.3mb transfer, progressively slowing.

I then added another file and the same low speed at start, then closed and added audio only file and it suddenly incresed to 11+mb and stopped at 21 seconds left at 391mb transferred.  It then started after a while at 1.8mb per second? and took a long while? Is there some sort of burst write to usb on a laptop for hp? It just seems odd.  Should I delete all and set to fat 32 and seperate folders to 4gb? Is this going to solve the issue?

It said it was pre-loaded as file type ms-dos but I thought that was fat=4gb max files, if fat 32 also, (exfat is this also ms-dos file system, labelled as msdos on the drive and not potentially supported properly on linux?)

update> I just checked lsusb and this is what it showed (so how do I know which port is which for my keyboard :)  and the flashdrive says 2gb?

lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:5776 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 093a:2521 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a2c:2d23 China Resource Semico Co., Ltd

Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0930:6544 Toshiba Corp. TransMemory-Mini / Kingston DataTraveler 2.0 Stick (2GB)

Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

update: I have taken it back to the store and got the same item in a usb 3.0 in the same brand and I still have the same issue? It started out fine up to about 500mb transferred at about 20mb/s but then i'm now still waiting at 1.2mb/s?  What's slowing it down? Any ideas?  The files are below 4gb.

Answer (score 1):

I had an error eventually show up as "file system does not support symbolic links".  A link to a software program on the desktop was seemingly causing the issue. Used a zip file instead of unpacked files for blender software.